# custom composable snippet for marker not showing

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, google-maps-markers

I want to add a custom snippet to a marker using maps compose.
reading throught the docs I found this function `MarkerInfoWindow` and its excaly what i want but my custom composable is not shown when i click on the marker.

```
@GoogleMap{
// other code 
....

 MarkerInfoWindow(
                icon = getBitmapDescriptorFromDrawable(
                    context,
                    com.ata.reservation_hotel.R.drawable.icon_circle_white
                ),
                state = rememberMarkerState(position = LocationUtils.getPosition(currentLocation)),
                infoWindowAnchor = Offset(0.9f,0.1f),
                content = {
                    it.showInfoWindow()
                    CustomInfoWindow(title =  "Hotel renaissance", description = "256 avenue de perouse +" +
                            "133100 aix-en-provence")
                }
            )
}
@Composable
fun CustomInfoWindow(title: String?, description: String?) {

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(20.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(Color.White)
    ) {

        TextGlobal(text = title ?: "")
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(5.dp))
        TextGlobal(text = description ?: "")

    }

}
```

What im expecting is the custom composable to be shown instead of the standard snippet